# Grouping by id in across columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, grouping

I have a table with the following columns

```
timetrack_id | timetrack_length | timetrack_rate | timetrack_parent
```

the `timetrack_parent` holds a `timetrack_id` if the time tracking has been continued, but will be `0` if it has not.

I would like to pull back a single row for each timetrack_id, but combine the `timetrack_length` where `timetrack_parent = timetrack_id`. Then the rest of the values should be from the parent row (where timetrack_parent = 0 and rows exists with a timetrack_parent of this timetrack_id).

So for the following data

```
timetrack_id | timetrack_length | timetrack_rate | timetrack_parent
-------------+------------------+----------------+-------------------
1            | 5                | 20.00          | 0
2            | 7                | 20.00          | 0
3            | 8                | 20.00          | 0
4            | 20               | 20.00          | 1
5            | 15               | 25.00          | 1
6            | 6                | 30.00          | 3
```

I would return

```
1 | 40 | 20.00 | 0
2 | 7  | 20.00 | 0
3 | 14 | 20.00 | 0
```

I have the following query

```
SELECT `timetrack_id`, `timetrack_parent`, `timetrack_rate`, SUM(`timetrack_length`) 
FROM `timetrack` 
GROUP BY `timetrack_parent`, `timetrack_parent` = `timetrack_id`
```

This does Group the rows by `timetrack_parent` and `SUM` the `timetrack_length`, but this also groups those that have a `timetrack_parent` of 0, which are not related. This query also doesn't group where `timetrack_parent = timetrack_id`. I'm also not sure the other data from the *parent* row will always be returned.

So what is returned is

```
1 | 20 | 20.00 | 0
4 | 35 | 20.00 | 1
6 | 6  | 30.00 | 3
```

Can someone offer some direction please?

Comment: `timetrack_user_rate` where is this column ?

Comment: Updated - should have been just `timetrack_rate`

Comment: As you are grouping rows - what values should be returned for timetrack_rate and timetrack_parent (I note your query is in wrong order if you want sum as 2nd column)

Comment: The order of the columns is not important in this case. I also don't care what is in `timetrack_parent`. But I would like for `timetrack_rate` to be the value that is held in the parent row. I just need 1 row per `timetrack_id` where `timetrack_parent` = 0, then all those that have a `timetrack_parent` != 0 should combine where their `timetrack_parent` = `timetrack_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query should work. You need to join the table to itself to get the parent/child grouping & then add all of the parent rows (timetrack_parent=0)
and then do the grouping.

```
SELECT id1 timetrack_id, sum(len) sumlength, timetrack_rate, timetrack_parent FROM
(
SELECT a.timetrack_id id1, b.* FROM timetrack a
JOIN timetrack b ON a.timetrack_id=b.timetrack_parent
UNION ALL
SELECT c.timetrack_id, c.* FROM timetrack c
WHERE c.timetrack_parent=0
ORDER BY 4
) z
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: The inner order by 4 puts the parent record at the top, which is then used by the outer group by.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not work. 1, This only returns rows if they have children. 2, Then `timetrack_length` of the parent is not added in the sum. 3, The `timetrack_rate` is not taken from the parent row. Any ideas?

Comment: I got the where clause wrong in the 2nd union select - I have edited the answer